# Setting up jwt or oauth in web application

Tags: angular, security, xss, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm buliding a new spa app using angular 4 and I've started to search for different options for implementing security. As I dived deeper I found every mechanisim very vulnerable to basic attacks. I wonder what is the most rewarding way to implement security in a small web application without the deep need for background knowledge in security world. here is my thoughts and questsions:

1. Using a session , the cookie can be very easly stolen using a simple CSRF.
2. Using a token based approach, I found to have few options and drawbacks.

   - Create a token and save expiration in database , on each request to server ,server will increase the expiration in X time. 
     This solution is very dangerous. if malicious user steals the token , he can easly keep it alive forever.
   - OAuth2 - use a refresh_token with access_token. This is great protocol for server where the refresh_token can be saved in server side. the problem is that both the access_token and refresh_token will be saved in client side in the same place. It will be easy to steal the refresh_token as it will be with the access_token using a simple XSS.
   - token with non expended expiration- after user will be authetnicated, he will recive a token with expiration of X minutes. after expiration, user will be navigated to login page. This is awful in product point of view, but the easiest to implement and the most secure in my not-professional-at-all opinon.
3. Storage-where to save the tokens/sessionId?

   - local storage - very easy to steal using simple xss, or someone with access to computer.
   - session storage- same as above , but with shorter living time.
   - cookie - easly can be stolen by simple CSRF or simple xss
   - cookie (Http-Only) - not sure about CSRF but blocks javascript access only in some of the browsers (if I understand correctly)
4. My suggestion (Will really like feedback)
     I thought about using some kind of symetric encryption in the client side. 
     When I will get the token from server I will encrypt it with some accessable data like browsertpye,operation etc... Although the encryption algorithm will be in the client, the javascipt is obfuscated which will add one more layer of difficulty to hack.

We build a web application with a low budget, and can't efford spending to much time on this. Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: How would you steal a cookie with CSRF?

Comment: Also read http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/19/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions-part-2-why-your-solution-doesnt-work/ and http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Answer (score 1):

We use tokens and they are great! Your fears are the same fears I had but here are a couple things to remember.

- If you are saving any "state" information on the server, the point of using a token just went out the window. The whole point is to simplify and reduce the footprint of the "authentication/authorization" system on the server. Tokens were the answer in that once the server signs it and sends it, there's nothing remaining on the server until it has to verify it for an incoming request.
- Use HTTPS. This way unless someone gains physical access to a computer with a valid token, and further knows what they are looking for and how to extract it, the likelihood of someone replaying a token is low. This particular fear is one we developers like to blow way out of the realm of reasonable probability.
- If security is that big of a deal, make your tokens expire after 24 hours, period. Don't worry about resetting their expiry. Most people don't care about logging back into a system, especially if the interval is reasonable.
- Your token server should have certain security levers built in. If you suspect that a number of tokens have been owned, the server should be able to be restarted, and generate it's own token secret on every boot up, this will invalidate any token out there (the big red button, if you will).
- Save as little information in the token as possible, it's not mobile storage. In fact your client shouldn't even be able to decrypt the token.